# How do i force browsers to wait until everything has loaded?

Tags: dom, pageload

I am working on a page that uses a few layers of stacked images and animations to produce an effect, however when i load it locally in every browser (latest versions) it will show the back hidden layers which are smaller in size than the front layer, but which are lower in the DOM, before it will show the front layer. This is only for a moment but it breaks the effect. The only browser that doesnt do this is chrome.

So far ive tried this:

```
<head>
$(window).load(function() {
    $(body).css("visibility", "visible");
});
</head>
    <body style="visibility:hidden;" >
```

but to no avail. Does anyone have a better method?

Answer (score 0):

/*USE This It may help you*/

```
function loadvisiblity()
{
    $(body).css("visibility", "visible");
}

<style type="text/css">
body.hidden {visibility:hidden;}
</style>

<body class="hidden" onload="loadvisiblity()">
```

Comment: I guess im gonna have to use a preloader as there doesnt appear to be any way to prevent the browser from showing elements as they are loaded.